# Python - creating string from dict items (for writing to postgresql db)

Tags: python, string, postgresql, dictionary, string-formatting

I'm writing some code using `psycopg2` to connect to a PostGreSQL database.

I have a lot of different data types that I want to write to different tables in my PostGreSQL database. I am trying to write a function that can write to each of the tables based on a single variable passed in the function and I want to write more than 1 row at a time to optimize my query. Luckily PostGreSQL allows me to do that: [PostGreSQL Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
('B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
('HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy');
```

I have run into a problem that I was hoping someone could help me with.

I need to create a string:

```
string1 = (value11, value21, value31), (value12, value22, value32)
```

The `string1` variable will be created by using a dictionary with values. So far I have been able to create a tuple that is close to the structure I want. I have a list of dictionaries. The list is called `rows`:

```
string1 = tuple([tuple([value for value in row.values()]) for row in rows])
```

To test it I have created the following small `rows` variable:

```
rows = [{'id': 1, 'test1': 'something', 'test2': 123},
        {'id': 2, 'test1': 'somethingelse', 'test2': 321}]
```

When rows is passed through the above piece of code `string1` becomes as follows:

```
((1, 'something', 123), (2, 'somethingelse', 321))
```

As seen with `string1` I just need to remove the outmost parenthesis and make it a string for it to be as I need it. So far I don't know how this is done. So my question to you is: "How do I format `string1` to have my required format?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`execute_values`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) makes it much easier. Pass the dict sequence in instead of a values sequence:

```
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras

rows = [
    {'id': 1, 'test1': 'something', 'test2': 123},
    {'id': 2, 'test1': 'somethingelse', 'test2': 321}
]

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='cpn')
cursor = conn.cursor()

insert_query = 'insert into t (id, test1, test2) values %s'
psycopg2.extras.execute_values (
    cursor, insert_query, rows,
    template='(%(id)s, %(test1)s, %(test2)s)',
    page_size=100
)
```

And the values are inserted:

```
table t;
 id |     test1     | test2 
----+---------------+-------
  1 | something     |   123
  2 | somethingelse |   321
```

To have the number of affected rows use a CTE:

```
insert_query = '''
    with i as (
        insert into t (id, test1, test2) values %s
        returning *
    )
    select count(*) from i
'''
psycopg2.extras.execute_values (
    cursor, insert_query, rows,
    template='(%(id)s, %(test1)s, %(test2)s)',
    page_size=100
)
row_count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Does `execute_values` support Python3?

Comment: @Zeliax I tested it in Python3. `execute_values` is new in Psycopg 2.7. Check your version: `psycopg2.__version__`

Comment: Thanks. I just updated it. I was on 2.6.2. Will check if this method does the trick. Do I need to `execute` and do a `conn.commit()` after the last line in your code snippet?

Comment: Lastly, what does the `page_size=100` mean? Is that how many are inserted in each "pass-through"?

Comment: @Zeliax Yes, if there are more than that another `insert` will be executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144934/discussion-between-zeliax-and-clodoaldo-neto).

Answer (score 2):

With little modification you can achieve this.
change your piece of cod as follows

```
','.join([tuple([value for value in row.values()]).__repr__() for row in rows])
```

## current output is

tuple of tuple

> (('something', 123, 1), ('somethingelse', 321, 2))

## After changes output will be

in string  format as you want

> "('something', 123, 1),('somethingelse', 321, 2)"

Comment: Thanks. This is just what I needed. I just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: sorry my first language is not English! guessing answer is useful :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you described is not so well because potentially it may harm your database – that solution does not care about escaping string, etc. So SQL injection is possible.
Fortunately, psycopg (and psycopg2) has cursor's [methods](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html) `execute` and `mogrify` that will properly do all this work for you:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(db_connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    values = [cursor.mogrify('(%(id)s, %(test1)s, %(test2)s)', row) for row in rows]
    query = 'INSERT INTO films (id, test1, test2) VALUES {0};'.format(', '.join(values))
```

For python 3:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(db_connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    values = [cursor.mogrify('(%(id)s, %(test1)s, %(test2)s)', row) for row in rows]
    query_bytes = b'INSERT INTO films (id, test1, test2) VALUES ' + b', '.join(values) + b';'
```

Comment: Yeah. My plan was to use the `cursor.execute(query, inputs)` method to do this, but I ended up having some problems with that. However I can't specifically remember what those problems entailed right now

Comment: Sorry for the spam comments. But the method I have should be able to adapt to the kinds of data that I pass. I will be passing a lot of different data of different data types for a lot of different tables, which should all go through this one function.

Comment: @Zeliax `mogrify` can format any data types just with '%s'

Comment: I see. I just tried to test your piece of code out and it makes great sense. I couldn't get it to work however. I assume `db_connection` should be my connection element? I have just named it `conn`. I get an error when I try to execute it, and that is after I have renamed my connection element. `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: It's a psycopg2 connection http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant.

Comment: Please see my comment above

Comment: What line produced that error? And which version of python are you using - 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python3 and trying to execute the line in the console gave me this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-228-17bc68d68c83>", line 9, in <module>
    query = 'INSERT INTO films (id, test1, test2) VALUES {0};'.format(', '.join(values))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
`

Comment: @Zeliax, I see now. I was checking it in python 2. I can't test it properly in python 3 right now, but I just added a piece of code that should work in python 3. `query_bytes` is a bytes query ready for execution. You can convert it to unicode with `query_str = query_bytes.decode('utf-8')` (or other encoding that is used in your database) if you need str.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out! :D